# Plotting Lennard-Jones potential for Argon

Tags: potential-energy, computational-physics, visualization

I am trying to understant the Lennard-Jones potential better by trying to plot it (for Argon) with the associated interatomic force, so I have:  $U(r)=\frac{B}{r^{12}}-\frac{A}{r^6},\ A=1.024\cdot 10^{-23} J\cdot nm^6,\ B=1.582\cdot 10^{-26}J\cdot nm^{12}$ and $F(r)=12\frac{B}{r^{13}}-6\frac{A}{r^7}$. I also divided $A$ and $B$ by Boltzmann's constant $k_B=1.381\cdot 10^{-23}J/K$ to measure $U(r)$ in units of $K$. By using the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

r = np.linspace(0.01,0.02,1000)

A = 1.024 * 10**(-23)
B = 1.582 * 10**(-26)
k = 1.381 * 10**(-23)

A_k = A/k
B_k = B/k

U = B_k/r**12 - A_k/r**6
line_1 = plt.plot(r, U, 'b', label = 'L-J potential')
plt.ylabel('Lennard-Jones potential')

plt.twinx()

m_dU = 12*B_k/r**13 - 6*A_k/r**7
line_2 = plt.plot(r, m_dU, 'r', label = 'interatomic force')
plt.ylabel('Interatomic force')

labels = []
lines = line_1 + line_2
for line in lines:
    labels.append(line.get_label())

plt.legend(lines, labels)
plt.show()
```

I get

[image: Lennard-Jones plot for Argon]

which doesn't look right to me, compared with the other visualization I have seen of Lennard-Jones potentials, with a very clear minimum, so I would be grateful if someone could point out to me if I have gotten the physics wrong or if it is my code that doesn't work and in that case if there is a better way to visualize it. Thank you.

Comment: Please, take into account that questions like this are considered check-my-work and are considered inappropriate on this site. The minimum of  the                                                                                                                  LJ potential, using your units should lay around 0.38, quite beyond the interval of distances you plot here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the scale of the $y$ axis. It's $10^{21}$. Why do you expect that you are able to see a small change around $y=0$ is the $y$-axis is scaled like this. You have to "fine tune" the plotted $x$-range, such that you zoom into the region around $y\approx 0$.